# Replace some string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
var x="45ab6eb6f099e866a97a10famount%5D=7.00";
```

I need to replace the value after `amount%5D=`. i.e. I need to make `...amount%5D=56.00` etc.

The main thing is that the string before and after  `amount%5D` is always changing.

i.e. it may be

```
sdd45ab6eb6f099e866a97a10famount%5D=4.00
gdfgdtgtrrtamount%5D=3.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There area a few ways to do this:

1: Regular expression:

```
x.replace(/(.+%5D=).+/, '$1' + yourNewValue);
```

2: String split:

```
var parts = x.split('%5D=');
var newString = parts[0] + '%5D=' + yourNewValue;
```

Comment: $('#myform form [name="item_amount"]').val(res.appointment_meta.owing);  this work. can you please explain how to assign this to variable.  var y=val(res.appointment_meta.owing); is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use `replace(regExp, 'replacement')`. Here is a quick example on how you might do this for x and x1 with a regular expression matching the pattern `/amount%5D=[0-9]+.[0-9]+/`.

```
// test with first variable
var x="45ab6eb6f099e866a97a10famount%5D=7.00";
var y = x.replace(/amount%5D=[0-9]+.[0-9]+/, "amount%5D=235.00");
console.log(y)
var y = x.replace(/amount%5D=[0-9]+.[0-9]+/, "amount%5D=12.00");
console.log(y)
var y = x.replace(/amount%5D=[0-9]+.[0-9]+/, "amount%5D=11.00");
console.log(y)

// test with new variable
var x1="dsf45ab6eb6f099e866a97amount%5D=7.00";
var y = x1.replace(/amount%5D=[0-9]+.[0-9]+/, "amount%5D=235.00");
console.log(y)
var y = x1.replace(/amount%5D=[0-9]+.[0-9]+/, "amount%5D=12.00");
console.log(y)
var y = x1.replace(/amount%5D=[0-9]+.[0-9]+/, "amount%5D=11.00");
console.log(y)
```

Output

```
45ab6eb6f099e866a97a10famount%5D=235.00
45ab6eb6f099e866a97a10famount%5D=12.00
45ab6eb6f099e866a97a10famount%5D=11.00
dsf45ab6eb6f099e866a97amount%5D=235.00
dsf45ab6eb6f099e866a97amount%5D=12.00
dsf45ab6eb6f099e866a97amount%5D=11.00
```

You could be more restrictive on the regular expression (e.g., only 2 decimal places allowed). This expression is only for illustration purposes.